# Automate the login process of Oracle Cloud Interface

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I have an web application a running on my local machine. There is a link in the view page to go to **Oracle Cloud Interface** dashboard. Upon clicking the link, `idcs` login page appears. Provided the credentials, the dashboard appears.

Is there any way to automate the login process under the hood? I don't want users to put credentials every time when anyone wants to visit the dashboard page.

Comment: Does it mean all your users are using the same username/password to login and view the Dashboard? Why can't your users use the Standard "Remember Password" Browser Capability? Basically you are asking a way to automate the username/password field entry on webpage, I guess you can use Selenium for that if you are already aware of the credentials of your users. Another way for passwordless entry is via Oracle Mobile Authenticator which requires app in user's mobile device.

Comment: @AmeenAliShaikh so, there is no easy way out. I was hoping that using `httpurlconnection` I could submit a form post action and get the cookies. Then set the cookies in the header of OCI dashboard URL before redirecting it to a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Configure and enable Single Sign-on (SSO) on Oracle Cloud on your tenancy. Set SSO as default login. Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/content-cloud/administer/enable-single-sign-sso.html

After this any external user logs in, he would be redirected to SSO login page, if the user is already logged in with SSO, it would even bypass SSO login and he will directly land in the OCI console/dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the token-based authentication method? You could use OCI CLI to get the token and then use it in your automation code. You can use the SDKs to automate the whole process and SDKs can use the same token for OCI authentication.

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/clitoken.htm

Thanks.

Comment: this article shows how to use the auth token to access the resources; i.e. retrieve user list or region. I get this part. But can I use this token to access a secured OCI url in the browser? i.e. the OCI dashboard or anything that needs to be authenticated before accessing in the browser.